# hide drop down menu on scroll JS only

Tags: javascript

Could you please give me tips how to make drop-down menu disappear on scroll up and down?

It is a little bit hard to find it in pure js. Just what path to follow and I will figure out myself.

```js
window.onsrcoll = function(){
     var position = 0;
     var scPos = (this.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) - (document.documentElement.clientTop || 0);
     position += scPos;
     if(position > scPos) {
      // code here to hide drop-down menu.
     }
    }
```

```css
/* on smaller size screens when it becomes drop down menu */
@media(max-width: 880px) {
#navi {
  display: none;
}
.navWrapper label[for="mygtukas"] {
  background: url(images/open.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2%;
  filter: invert(85%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.navWrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #navi {
  display: block;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navWrapper" >
   <h1 id="myLogo"><span class="initial">E.</span><span class="name">Erlandas</span> Petronis</h1>
   <div class="shadow"></div>
   <label for="mygtukas" id="icon"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="mygtukas">
   <ul id="navi">
    <li id="li"><a id="link" class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="li"><a id="link" href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li id="li"><a id="link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="li"><a id="link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

JS does not work, at least does not make sense or am i off the track here?

Comment: Can you show your HTML please?

Comment: What is your definition of a *drop-down menu*? There are many things that could be this, from a simple `<select>` to a complicated menu structure (and several things in between)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question - edited.

Comment: noticed a typo in `window.onscroll`

Answer (score 1):

As I can see that you want to make the drop-down menu disappear when scrolling down.

One way to do it would be by using Javascript.

What you can do is take the `getElementById` to change the style top of the navbar to make it disappear when scrolling down.

You can do something like this in javascript :

```js
var position = window.pageYOffset;
window.onsrcoll = function(){
     var scPos = window.pageYOffset;
     if(position>scPos) {
      document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
     } else {
      document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
     }
      position = scPos;
    }
```

For this to work, you'll have to give your navbar a `position: fixed;` and `top: 0;`

[Hide menu on scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp)